# Proper subtitle in the resume

Tags: clauses

[image]

> 2016.04    Unity Games
>
> Personal Projects which help gain an insight into modern game engine

Adding "which" in a subtitle seems not concise. I am wondering if I can substitute it with

> Personal Projects helping gain an insight into modern game engine

The following item has the same problem.

> 2015.08    3D Movie Generator
>
> Project which is conducted during my internship and finally becomes my graduate design

Can I substitute the above subtitle with the following one?

> Project conducted during my internship and finally becoming my graduate design

Comment: None of these are really _sentences,_ and "subscript" doesn't mean what you think it does, but aside from that, please use the [edit] link to tell us exactly what usage you are asking about. Proofreading is specifically off-topic here. Have you read our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages?

Comment: I would stay away from *ing* forms on a resume.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Very sorry about this. I should use "subtitle" instead of "subscript". However, I don't quite understand the definition of proofreading. I am just asking some usages I am confused about. Can I ask like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your sentences are really *natural* English (or grammatically correct), but the meaning comes across nevertheless.  If you're worried that you don't sound like a native speaker when applying for game-development jobs, I'm afraid you have a lot more studying to do.

But if you're just trying to list the things you've done, and you know gaming companies don't really care about English fluency, then you're OK with what you have.

So, that being said:

> I developed personal projects which helped give me an insight into (working with) modern game engines.
>
> I worked on this project during my internship (with Unity Games) and later applied it to my design for my (MS? BS?) degree in Computer Science.

Comment: Maybe I should use "subtitle" to describe my question more correctly instead of "subscript". What I need is a subtitle (an apposition which gives more detailed information) but not a full sentence. Well, I should admit I am bad in English. Thank you.

Comment: Well, as a technical professional I can assure you I'm much more interested in how you write code than how you speak English.  As long as we can communicate, it's all good.  Anyway you can see in my answers that using "which" is fine.  Clarity is more important than brevity.